# Javascript / jQuery Windows 8 On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows, windows-8, keyboard

I'm trying to build an application where if the user activates a page, a focus event will occur and focus into a text field. I was half-heartedly expecting that when I called `.focus()` on in the input box, Windows 8 would pop-up the on-screen keyboard. This in not the case.

Does anyone know of a way to get the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard to come up when the text field is focused via javascript.

If the user "taps" into the textfield, the focus event does fire and the keyboard comes up.

I've tried binding to `touchstart`, '`touchend`, `click` and `focus`, but all of these do not seem to activate the on-screen keyboard.

This application will run strictly on Windows 8, so there is no need to make it so that other platforms that do not have built-in on-screen keyboards work properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  Only user actions can open the on-screen keyboard.  This is by design.  See [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithhtml5/thread/225025e1-ef9e-4044-a635-563027ed78eb#29feeaa9-3763-4cdb-ab64-4a0e0cfa7169).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I designed the application to indicate that the user needs to "Tap here" to begin searching.